# show the block form when the mouse hover on the toplink div

Tags: jquery

the mouse will hover on block html:

```
<div class="toplinks">...</div>
```

the show block content html:

```
<div id="pop-login" style:"display:none;">...some content and a form</div>
```

my jquery code:

```
$('.toplinks').hover(function(){

    $('#pop-login').toggle();
    $('#pop-login').toggleClass("hpposition");
});
```

the css:

```
.hpposition{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left:500px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

now, there comes a problem, when the mouse move out the `toplinks`div. i can't fill something to the showing form. when the mouse moves out the   `toplinks` div. the form disappear immediately. how to make that the use can fill some content to the form?

Comment: How about putting this in a fiddle?

Comment: Did you try putting your form div inside the div you have the hover handler attached to? See if this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/UQv9a/1/) is close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<div class="toplinks">
    <div id="pop-login" style:"display:none;">...some content and a form</div>
</div>
<script>
$('.toplinks').hover(function() {
    $('#pop-login').toggle();
});
</script>
```